# Trouble plotting 1/(x^2-1)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the function 1/(x^2-1) on a Cartesian plane. This is what I have so far, but it isn't working. What can I do to fix it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.5pt}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},
   ylabel={$~~y$},
   axis equal,
   axislines=middle,
   width=8cm,height=5cm,
   xmin=-3,xmax=3,
   ymin=-3,ymax=3,
   yticklabel=\empty,
   xticklabel=\empty,
   ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty
]
    \addplot [red,thick,smooth] {(x^2-1)^{-1}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I apologise for the mess, I'm still getting used to use Tikz.

Comment: Welcome! I believe it should be `{(x^2-1)^(-1)}` or `{1/(x*x-1)}`. Also the domain has singularities.

Comment: Keep in mind that x^2 is computed using exp(2*log(x)) instead of x*x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to punch in the function in a way it can be understood by the parser. Also there should be a space in `axis lines`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},
   ylabel={$y$},
   axis equal,
   axis lines=middle,
   width=8cm,height=5cm,
   xmin=-3,xmax=3,
   ymin=-3,ymax=3,
   yticklabel=\empty,
   xticklabel=\empty,
   ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,
   unbounded coords=jump
]
    \addplot [red,thick,smooth,domain=-3:3,samples=101] {1/(x*x-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use (x)^2 instead of x*x?

Comment: +1 I think I'd specify the domain to avoid the asymptotes.